# Javascript dynamic onChange event on select

Tags: javascript, html, select, web

I have this javascript snippet:

```
var selectName["id1","id2","id3"];
setOnClickSelect = function (prefix, selectName) {
        for(var i=0; i<selectName.length; i++) {
            var selId = selectName[i];
            alert(selId);
            $(selId).onchange = function() {
                $(selId).value = $(selId).options[$(selId).selectedIndex].text;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I change value to my id1 element, the alert wrote me always "id3".
Can I fix it?

EDIT:
I've changed my snippet with these statements:

```
setOnChangeSelect = function (prefix, selectName) {
        for(var i=0; i<selectName.length; i++) {
            var selId = selectName[i];
            $(selId).onchange = (function (thisId) {
                return function() {
                    $(selId).value = $(thisId).options[$(thisId).selectedIndex].text;
                }
            })(selId);
        }
    }
```

But selId is always the last element.

Comment: var selectName["id1","id2","id3"]; 

Just a correction

Comment: selID inside the `onchange` callback function will always point to the last element after the loop. The code I edited is to create another scope to maintain the `selId` with `thisId` within the loop and which could be referred back in the callback function.    What you are trying to archieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the behavior of [javaScript Closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), `selId` has been set to the `selectName[2]` at the end of the loop and that's why you get 'id3' back.

An fix is as following, the key is wrap the callback function inside another function to create another closure.

```
var selectName = ["id1","id2","id3"];

var setOnClickSelect = function (prefix, selectName) {
        for(var i = 0; i < selectName.length; i++) {
            var selId = selectName[i];
            $(selId).onchange = (function (thisId) {
              return function() {
                $(thisId).value = $(thisId).options[$(thisId).selectedIndex].text;
              }
            })(selId);
        }
    };
```

Ps: there is synyax error for `var selectName["id1","id2","id3"]`, you should use `var selectName = ["id1","id2","id3"];`

Comment: I've answered you to main post.